# call a stored procedure from PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, stored-procedures, jdbc

I am trying to call a stored procedure.
A stored procedure is proven by tests in the database and executed

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION statapi.pui_src_ter(p_src_ter_id id_t, p_aname name_t, p_adesc desc_t, p_sortord sortord_t)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    afected_rows integer := 0;
BEGIN
update statdwh.src_ter
   set  aname = p_aname,
    adesc = p_adesc,
    sortord = p_sortord,
    actdt = current_timestamp
 where src_ter_id = p_src_ter_id;
get diagnostics afected_rows = row_count;
if (afected_rows = 0) then
    insert into statdwh.src_ter(src_ter_id, aname, adesc, sortord, actdt)
        values (p_src_ter_id, p_aname, p_adesc, p_sortord, current_timestamp)
        returning src_ter_id into p_src_ter_id;
    get diagnostics afected_rows = row_count;
end if;

return afected_rows;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION statapi.pui_src_ter(id_t, name_t, desc_t, sortord_t)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

the call itself

```
public void storedProcedureCall() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    CallableStatement cst = connection.prepareCall("{call statapi.pui_src_ter(?,?,?,?)}");
    cst.setInt(1, 11);
    cst.setString(2, "aname_att");
    cst.setString(3, "adesc_att");
    cst.setInt(4, 222);
    ResultSet result3 = cst.executeQuery();
    while (result3.next()){
        System.out.println(result3.getString(1));
    }
    cst.execute();
}
```

returns "1" as expected, since modified one record, but in the database (I look through pgAdmin) record does not appear
 What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you commit the transaction?

Answer (score 0):

Senior fellow replied simply "add connection.commit();"